# How do I keep my Android 4.0.3 phone awake when USB connected?

Tags: screen

On my old [Android 2.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#2.3.x_Gingerbread) (Gingerbread) phone there was an option to keep my phone awake when the USB cable was connected. But on my [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II), (4.0.3) I can not find it. Does the option still exist?

**EDIT:** If I go to *settings* > *Developer options*, then my options are:

```
USB debugging
Allow mock locations
Desktop backup password
strict mode enabled
pointer location
show touches
show screen updates
show CPU usage
Force GPU rendering
Window animation scale
Transition animation scale
don't keep activities
Background process limit
Show all ANR's
```

... and nothing else.

I just went to *software update* > *check for updates*, and was told "no update available".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have checked on my two Ice Cream Sandwich Devices (Stock Xoom and Droid 3 running CM9 Beta). I have, under `Settings > Developer Options` a `Stay Awake` option. Which keeps your device awake when charging.

[image: Screenshot of Droid 3 Developer Options Window in CM9]

This will work if your device charges over USB (my Xoom does not, for instance).

However, should this option not be there, we can turn to apps for help!

[StayAwake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji) looks like it could be a solution to your problem.

[WakeLocker for Galaxy S](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.xii.relog.wakelocker) also looks to be a solution.

Answer (score 6):

The Samsung Galaxy S II does not have this feature, and never has, because of its [AMOLED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOLED) screen.

They burn (like [CRTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)) if they have the same picture on the screen for too long. For some reason apps can still lock the screen on, but you can't do it from settings.

(My Samsung Galaxy S II has burn in from the notification bar.)

You can use [StayAwake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji), just don't forget to turn it off.

Answer (score 5):

On my Galaxy Nexus it can found under

Settings/Developer Options/Stay Awake.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this kind of solution for app development, then I have created an app for this purpose ([Keep Awake for Debugging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arpitgupta.keepawakefordebugging)). It will keep your screen on **only** when you have ADB (over USB or wifi) debugging enabled.

**It supports only android 4.2 and above.**