# Do not go into standby when phone is plugged in

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, standby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I keep my Android 4.0.3 phone awake when USB connected?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/how-do-i-keep-my-android-4-0-3-phone-awake-when-usb-connected)

Is it possible to configure my S2 so that when it is plugged in, the phone doesn't go into standby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Android are you running? In CyanogenMod and other versions look in SETTINGS > DEVELOPER OPTIONS > STAY AWAKE / KEEP SCREEN ON WHILE CHARGING

You might also want to take a look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fruit4droid.anyscreentimeout), if the options aren't available to you.

Seems like this question has been answered earlier - [How do I keep my Android 4.0.3 phone awake when USB connected?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/how-do-i-keep-my-android-4-0-3-phone-awake-when-usb-connected)

Comment: Disregard comment - now checking out CyanogenMod.